# How to know which icons are provided by AppIndicator?

Tags: python, gtk

I'm using a few icons included in `AppIndicator` and `AppIndicator3` (from `gi.repository`), such as gsm-3g-full and gsm-3g-none.

How can one know which other icons are available?  There does not seem to exist much documentation about it.  [This tutorial](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) does not mention AppIndicator at all.

EDIT: I'm looking for the icons' pictures, but if this isn't possible even knowing the icons' names would be very useful.

Comment: First Google result for "appindicator icon names"....

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Do you mean http://askubuntu.com/questions/46761/how-do-i-get-the-names-in-my-icon-theme-for-use-with-pythons-appindicator-module/46763? Not very helpful. Answers are from 2011 and they don't work anymore.

Comment: What about them "don't work"? It's always best if you ask direct, specific questions. Perhaps we can get those answers working again?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I managed to obtain the list of icons' names thanks to one of the answers. I'll rewrite it below.

Comment: Yay, there you go!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the accepted answer to [this question on AU](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46761/how-do-i-get-the-names-in-my-icon-theme-for-use-with-pythons-appindicator-module/46763):

```
import gtk

icon_theme = gtk.icon_theme_get_default()
print icon_theme.list_icons()
```

This generates a tuple of all icons' names: `('input-gaming', 'gnome-aorta', 'stock_bottom', 'config-language', ...)`

To visualize icons, we can use the command `gtk3-icon-browser` which is provided by package `libgtk-3-dev` on Ubuntu, and `gtk3-devel` on Fedora.

#### Update for Ubuntu 18.04 and up:

Package changed to: `gtk-3-examples`

Comment: GTK+ 3.14 and newer come with a program `gtk3-icon-browser` that does this all for you. You should be able to just run it from the command line. Keep in mind that these icon names are a generally accepted/partially de facto standard, not exclusive to AppIndicator, so you can safely use them elsewhere as well.

Comment: @andlabs Thanks, added to my answer for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

If using the modern, recommended bindings from `gi` instead of the deprecated `gtk`, the syntax is slightly different::

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
theme = Gtk.IconTheme.get_default()
for icon in theme.list_icons(None):  # None as context lists all icons
    print(icon)
```